# One year old pulmaria losing leaves

Tags: plant-health

I have a less the one year old pulmaria in a pot and the leaves are one by one turning brown shriveling up and dying and falling off one a day. Can you help me stop it? There is nothing on the leaves they look perfectly fine but then one a day one leaf will dye. Is this normal what am I doing wrong.

Comment: plumeria or pulmonaria? Also, please post a photo.

Comment: Plumeria goes dormant when I bring it indoors for the Winter. Probably not in the tropics.